# Can a Lenovo Thinkpad X201 (4GB RAM, 120 GB SSD) run the latest ArcGIS software?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hardware

I'm a GIS student and I usually run Linux on my laptop, but I'm starting to get sick of having to run to the computer lab every time I have to do some work with ArcGIS + ArcCatalog.

If I were to remove Linux completely, install Windows 7 since I think I have a license for it, then maybe install Windows 10 on said machine if necessary, would I be able to run ArcGIS reasonably smoothly?

I would do the research myself but I'm not sure if my graphics card, for example, meets the minimum requirements. Please don't just link me to the minimum requirements page and the Thinkpad X201 specs because I can't make heads or tails of some of the requirements and if my machine meets them.

Do you have any anecdotes on running ArcGIS on similarly specced machines?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: What type of work are you planning to run on it?  I imagine the laptop will be able to run ArcGIS Desktop, but how well it runs it will depend on the type of work and the type of data you are using.  Small datasets with no processing can run on much less than major processing on huge datasets.

Comment: I think this question in its current state would be fine for the GIS Chat Room.

Comment: Do you need to use ArcGIS because you are learning ArcGIS, or are you using ArcGIS because you need to solve some GIS problem.  If the latter, why not use QGIS / SAGA / GRASS etc on your Linux laptop?

Comment: @nmtoken I'm using it specifically to learn ArcGIS otherwise I'd gladly stick to my Linux laptop

Answer (score 1):

ArcMap is 32 bit, so it won't be able to use more than 2 GB RAM.  You'll be able to run it just fine.  If you're using ArcGIS Pro, you may be able to get more performance from a bigger machine.  CPU processing speed makes the most difference as it rarely uses multiple cores (some raster processing).  The only area where a better graphics card makes a difference is in drawing speed, which can be an issue sometimes.  All in all, as long as you aren't working with huge data files, you should be fine.

https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/pd010141

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/10.4/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a misleading answer. It assumes that no other applications are operating on the machine. In reality, 4Gb is 4-8Gb too little RAM for reasonable GIS performance.  Windows 7, by itself, uses 4+Gb of RAM, and it's my understanding that 10 is more profligate.  The real benefit to having adequate memory is allowing the OS to cache disk I/O, and you certainly won't have that in under 6Gb of RAM.

Comment: @Vince it all depends on the type of GIS work is being performed.  The laptop may perform fine with only 4GB of RAM for light GIS work - editing, a bit of coding, light geoprocessing - but may struggle with anything more intense.  My home PC has only 4GB and runs ArcGIS 10.5 no problem for writing and testing code and a bit of light work, but anything more intense I do on the work PC which has a lot more resources.

Comment: I see. I don't think I'm doing anything super heavy yet. Just working with attribute tables, queries, some map first, second order map transformations.

Comment: I think that will be all for now. I will be installing ArcGIS on my ThinkPad. Thanks for your help, everyone! :D

Comment: Update: ArcGIS works well on this laptop with W10. Sometimes the UI slows down a bit when doing some computational stuff, but it is good to use overall.